# Python: updating assigned variable created in other function

Tags: python

I am trying to create registration and login and forgot password functions.
this is my code

```
def regi():
    global new, unname, answer, passcode
    print('**New Registration**'.capitalize().center(100))
    uname = input("Enter User Name: ")
    passcode = input("Enter Password: ")
    questn()
    new = [name, uname, passcode, security]
    print(f'Your Business {bname} has created.\nWelcome to Business World')
    newbusiness()


def login():
    chances = 5
    global old
    userid = input('Enter User Id: ')
    password = input('Enter Password: ')
    try:
        if userid and password in new:
            pass
        else:
            print('Wrong Credentials')
            chances -= 1
            login()
    except NameError:
        print('No Username found. Please register.')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Redirecting to registration block.')
        time.sleep(2)
        regi()


def questn():
    global security
    questions = {
        1: 'What is your favourite color?',
        2: 'What is your mother tongue?',
        3: 'What is your favourite place of weekend?'
    }
    for k, v in questions.items(): print(f'{k}: {v}')
    qselct = input("Please select one security question: ")
    answr = input('Enter your answer: ')
    security = [qselct, answr]


def forgotpass():

    questions = {
        1: 'What is your favourite color?',
        2: 'What is your mother tongue?',
        3: 'What is your favourite place of weekend?'
    }
    for k, v in questions.items(): print(f'{k}: {v}')
    comparequet = input("Select Security Quesion: ")
    compareans = input("Enter your answer (Case Sensitive): ")
    if comparequet and compareans in security:
        passcode = input('Enter new password: ')  # i stuck here
```

when i try to reassign 'Passcode' using input(), in pycharm its giving this
**Shadows name 'passcode' from outer scope**

so how can i update passcode in regi(), here in forgotpass().

Note: helpful if you suggest any improvements in above code. I am using learned subject in the above code. learned TRY used there.

Comment: Get rid of all `global` variables and have your function expect arguments and return results.

Comment: Thats giving not defined errors in code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to bring in a

```py
global passcode
```

before using this variable.